# Estimating linear fit as a moving average

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

Say I have the following data:

```
Year  Day  Amount
2015  1    2
2015  2    3
2015  3    4
2015  4    5
```

Using window functions or aggregations, I want to get a number for each row that represents the "linearity based on the previous n rows". In this simple example, for the row with `day = 4`, linearity would be pretty high, for obvious reasons, based on the previous n days, where n is 3.

Issues pop up when some of the previous days do not exist, and in that case, I would just want to use a default value of -1, for example to indicate otherwise.

I don't have an exact value I want to represent the linearity, but as an example, similar to correlation coefficients, 1 could represent high linearity, while 0 none.

Edit:

What I have done as a makeshift use-case was add a column to each row representing the day (and taking year into account), and used a window function, with lag to find the previous 4 values (if they existed). After getting (or not getting these values), I made a simple calculation to calculate the difference of each combination of points, and used division to see how close they were to each other (1 would be the best). I apologize, I cannot share any code due to an agreement of code sharing.

Comment: So we know what you want. Now, what have you tried to achieve that?

Comment: @zero323 I have updated my question with what I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

- generate series with all dates you want to estimate
- left outer join it with input
- replace `null` values for `Amount` with a valuet to estimate
- convert to RDD
- generate keys with lower bound -> for `2015  4` generate keys [`2015  4`, `2015  3`, `2015  2`] amd flatten
- groupByKey
- estimate for groups

Comment: Can you go into more detail for "generate keys with lower bound"? Not sure exactly what you mean there.